# Addresses to do with illegal transactions

Tags: legal, hacking

I have been searching for sources to obtain illegal addresses used in high profile incidents such as the Mt. Gox hack, Stone Man Hack etc. It would be helpful if someone has this on hand.

Answer (score 0):

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=576337
I found this gem of a post for future reference